# Evaluate $\int \frac{dx}{(1-x^2)\sqrt[4]{(2x^2-1)}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How can we evaluate the following integral?

$$
\mathcal{I} = \int \frac{dx}{(1-x^2)\sqrt[4]{(2x^2-1)}}
$$

---

### Some notes...

1. Any standard integration methods (e.g., substitution method, integration by parts, etc.) does not work.
2. I tried using integral-calculator.com, it does not work either.
3. Trivially, I tried to set some possible limits (e.g., 0 $\rightarrow$ 1, $-\pi \rightarrow \pi$, etc.) — with no success.
4. This is not a homework question. I'm open to the ideas given by experts here.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5B1%2C%5C%2840%291-Power%5Bx%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29Surd%5B2Power%5Bx%2C2%5D-1%2C4%5D%5D%2Cx%5D

Comment: @SineoftheTime. This is awful ! Do you like it ? Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici yor're indeed right, it's awful aesthetically. I've just added the link because the OP said that he did not find the antiderivative using a calculator

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Substitute $t=\sqrt[4]{2x^2-1}$ to simplify the integral first

$$
I= \int \frac{1}{(1-x^2)\sqrt[4]{2x^2-1}}dx
= \frac1{\sqrt2}\int \frac{4 t^2}{(1-t^4)\sqrt{1+t^4}}dt
$$
and break up the integrand
$$
\frac{4 t^2}{(1-t^4)\sqrt{1+t^4}}
= \frac{t^2-1}{(1+t^2)\sqrt{1+t^4}}+ \frac{ t^2+1}{(1-t^2)\sqrt{1+t^4}}
$$
Then, the two resulting integrals are relatively easy to evaluate
\begin{align}
I= &\frac1{\sqrt2}\int \frac{t^2-1}{(1+t^2)\sqrt{1+t^4}}+ \frac{ t^2+1}{(1-t^2)\sqrt{1+t^4}}\ dt\\
=&\ \frac12\tan^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{1+t^4}{2t^2}}+ \frac12\coth^{-1}\sqrt{\frac{1+t^4}{2t^2}}+C
\end{align}
For example
$$\int \frac{t^2-1}{(1+t^2)\sqrt{1+t^4}}dt =
\int \frac{d(t+\frac1t)}{(t+\frac1t)\sqrt{(t+\frac1{t})^2-2}}
$$

Comment: The key is the second line. Nicely done

Answer (score 6):

Mathematica gives
$$I=\frac 12\left(\tanh ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt[4]{2 x^2-1}}\right)+\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt[4]{2 x^2-1}}\right)\right)+C$$

Comment: Beautiful and symmetric! +1

Comment: @NinadMunshi. I found  a mistake in my first answer. By the end, .... Mathematica. Cheers :-)

Comment: @NinadMunshi. Even knowing the result, the substitution is not clear. Any idea ?

Comment: Under the substitution $u = \sqrt{2x^2-1}$, it may be beneficial to consider the further substitution $$t = \sqrt{u +\frac{1}{u}}$$

Comment: looking at the answer, it is now obvious to apply the substitution 
$$u=\frac{x}{(2x^2-1)^{1/4}}$$
We can solve for x by taking the 4th power on each side and reducing it to a quadratic in $x^2$

Comment: Neat solution. Is there no way to see how it arrived at that solution?